# Messagebox shortcuts

Tags: c#, winforms

Is it possible to bind hotkeys to messagebox somehow?
Imagine a scenario, where a YES/NO messagebox is shown. So the idea is, user can select YES or NO button by hitting "y" or "n" on keyboard.

Thank you.

Comment: In this scenario where you wish to customise the messagebox control i think you would be wiser simply creating a custom messagebox in the way of a form.

Comment: Have you tried to press the Y or N when the messagebox is open? Or the appropriate letters for your locale?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So the idea is, user can select YES or NO button by hitting "y" or "n"
>   on keyboard

MessageBox already has that functionality. 
Suppose your MessageBox is defined as:

```
DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure ??", "Test Message Box", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
{
    //Yes pressed
}
else if (dialogResult == DialogResult.No)
{
    //No pressed
}
```

Then if you press `Y` on `N`, you will get the appropriate result. Check the following screen shot
[image]

Comment: I am sorry for silly question, the control I was showing to user looked too similar to .NET messagebox, but it wasn't standard MessageBox, and obviously had slightly different behaviour.

Comment: @Alex,@Habib: It was not mention how you have set shortcut key for yes.No click to 'Y','N'.

Comment: @Anand You don't have to set them, that's the point. `System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox` sets them for you by default.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to achieve that is to create your custom control/Messagebox in which you can design the behaviour of the window and assign hotkeys to it.

Answer (score -2):

Make a custom form , on button click do form.ShowDialog()

```
    if (e.KeyChar == Keys.Y)
        {
            button_yes.PerformClick();
        }
        else if(e.KeyChar == Keys.N)
        {
            button_no.PerformClick();
        }
```

:)